# Using strstr to find four different partial words

Tags: c, string

I am looking to find part of a string containing **TP2**, **DP3**, **OP1**, or **OP2**, in a text file.

On each line is a different set of characters and eventually these three characters are used, but they are never on the same line as each other.

I can get it to print once I find the **OP2**, but it will not print the three before it. If I comment out the **OP2** it finds **OP1** and if I do that to **OP1** and **OP2** it finds **DP3** and so on.

I do not get why it cannot print out all four different ones once found.

I used two different methods one where I `strcpy` into a `temp` and one I just print it as is and neither work.  Later I want it to print to the right of the `=` sign on the lines with the four search types, but I will work on that after I get the print issue fixed. Any help or reasons why would be much appreciated.

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < stdlib.h>
#include < string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 150

int main(void) {

    FILE *file1, *file2;
    char parts[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1];
    int len = strlen(parts);

    //char TP2[3] = "TP2";
    char DP3[3] = "DP3";
    char MOP1[3] = "OP1";
    //char MOP2[3] = "OP2";

    //char TP2Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char DP3Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char MOP1Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    //char MOP2Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    file1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    file2 = fopen("output2.txt", "w");

    if (file1 == NULL || file2 ==NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(parts, sizeof(parts), file1)!=NULL){
        if(parts[len -1 ] =='\n'){
            parts[len -1 ] ='\0';
        }
        //if(strstr(parts, TP2)!=NULL){
        //  strcpy(TP2Temp, parts);
        //  fprintf(file2, "%s", TP2Temp);
        //}
        if(strstr(parts,DP3)!=NULL){
            strcpy(DP3Temp, strstr(parts,DP3));
            fprintf(file2, "%s", DP3Temp);
        }
        else if(strstr(parts, MOP1)!=NULL){
            strcpy(MOP1Temp, strstr(parts,MOP1));
            fprintf(file2, "%s", MOP1Temp);
        }
        /*else if(strstr(parts, MOP2)!=NULL){
            strcpy(MOP2Temp, parts);
            fprintf(file2, "%s", MOP2Temp);
        }*/
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);

    return 0;
}


/*Here is the text file sample
TC_TP1[2]=1
TC_TP2[2]="9070036"
TC_TP3[2]=1
TC_TP4[2]=1
TC_TP5[2]=1
TC_TP6[2]=1
TC_TP7[2]=1
TC_DP1[2,1]=120
TC_DP2[2,1]=0
TC_DP3[2,1]=179.85
TC_DP4[2,1]=0
TC_DP5[2,1]=0
TC_MOP1[2,1]=3
TC_MOP2[2,1]=28
TC_MOP3[2,1]=0
TC_MOP4[2,1]=0
TC_TP1[3]=1
TC_TP2[3]="9005270"
TC_TP3[3]=1*/
```

Comment: `char DP3[3] = "DP3";` --> `char DP3[4] = "DP3";` or `char DP3[] = "DP3";`

Comment: `int len = strlen(parts);` move to before `if(parts[len -1 ] =='\n'){`

Comment: don't compute twice `strstr`, change `if(strstr(parts, MOP1)!=NULL){ strcpy(MOP1Temp, strstr(parts,MOP1));` to something like `if( (s=strstr(parts, MOP1))!=NULL){ strcpy(MOP1Temp, s));`

Comment: Thank you BLUEPIXY. I did both changes and it now prints out all four.  I just need to now get it to print values after the = sign for the lines found with the characters.  This definitely puts me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
char parts[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1];
int len = strlen(parts);
```

`parts` is uninitialised in this code, and thus isn't guaranteed to contain a string. Even if it were to, `len` would be initialised the length of that garbage string, which is meaningless and thus useless.

```
char DP3[3] = "DP3";
```

If your understanding of strings is valid, you should realise there are *four* characters in these strings. The following program demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("sizeof \"DP3\": %zu\n", sizeof "DP3");
}
```

You are reading a book to learn C, right? Your book would explain to you among many other things so we wouldn't need to, `strstr` requires its operands be *strings*, and *strings **always** contain a terminating `'\0'`*. Where's your terminating `'\0'`? How is `strstr` expected to know the length of the string pointed to by `DP3`?

Because the length of your tokens are at most three bytes, you currently only need to read and store at most three bytes at a time to conduct your search (four including the terminal byte explained above; untested&incomplete example below); this requirement could change, should you decide to introduce longer (or dynamically sized) tokens, your cursor will need to be as wide as your longest token.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned char item[4];
int item_cmp(void const *x, void const *y) {
    return memcmp(x, y, sizeof (item));
}
int main(void) {
    item cursor = "",
         haystack[] = { "TP1", "OP0", "OP1", "OP2", "TP0", "DP3", "OOO" };

    size_t size  = fread(cursor, sizeof cursor - 1, 1, stdin),
           nelem = sizeof haystack / sizeof *haystack;

    int c = 0, e = !size;

    qsort(haystack, nelem, sizeof *haystack, item_cmp);

    do {
        if (bsearch(cursor, haystack, nelem, sizeof *haystack, item_cmp)) {
            printf("match found for %s\n", cursor);
        }
        memmove(cursor, cursor + 1, sizeof cursor - 1);
        if (!e) {
            c = fgetc(stdin);
            e = c < 0 && feof(stdin);
        }
        cursor[size] = e || c == '\n' ? '\0' : c;
        size -= e;
    } while (size);

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again BLUEPIXY, with your information I was able to make the changes I needed and was able to extract the data where it found TP2 and then the value after the equal sign.  I am sure there is a nicer way to code this, but my solution is below.  I will add a change to be able to take in any file name and the reason for the

```
MOP1Equal[strlen(MOP1Equal) -1] ='\0';
```

was to make it in columns for a csv file to put in excel and the

```
fprintf(file2, "\t%s", MOP1Equal+1);
```

where I add 1 was to get rid of the = sign.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 150

int main(void) {

FILE *file1, *file2;
char parts[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1] = "startingvaluebeforechange";

char TP2[4] = "TP2";
char DP3[4] = "DP3";
char MOP1[4] = "OP1";
char MOP2[4] = "OP2";
char Equal[2] = "=";

char TP2Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char TP2Equal[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

char DP3Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char DP3Equal[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

char MOP1Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char MOP1Equal[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

char MOP2Temp[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char MOP2Equal[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

file1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
file2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");

if (file1 == NULL || file2 ==NULL) {
    exit(1);
}

while(fgets(parts, sizeof(parts), file1)!=NULL){
    int len = strlen(parts);
    if(parts[len -1 ] =='\n'){
        parts[len -1 ] ='\0';
    }
    if(strstr(parts, TP2)!=NULL){
        strcpy(TP2Temp, strstr(parts,TP2));
        strcpy(TP2Equal, strstr(TP2Temp,Equal));
        TP2Equal[strlen(TP2Equal) -2] ='\0';            
        fprintf(file2, "%s", TP2Equal+2);
    }
    if(strstr(parts,DP3)!=NULL){
        strcpy(DP3Temp, strstr(parts,DP3));
        strcpy(DP3Equal, strstr(DP3Temp,Equal));
        DP3Equal[strlen(DP3Equal) -1] ='\0';
        fprintf(file2, "\t%s", DP3Equal+1);
    }
    if(strstr(parts, MOP1)!=NULL){
        strcpy(MOP1Temp, strstr(parts,MOP1));
        strcpy(MOP1Equal, strstr(MOP1Temp,Equal));
        MOP1Equal[strlen(MOP1Equal) -1] ='\0';
        fprintf(file2, "\t%s", MOP1Equal+1);
    }
    if(strstr(parts, MOP2)!=NULL){
        strcpy(MOP2Temp, strstr(parts,MOP2));
        strcpy(MOP2Equal, strstr(MOP2Temp,Equal));
        fprintf(file2, "\t%s", MOP2Equal+1);
    }
}
fclose(file1);
fclose(file2);
return 0;
```

}